# Convert datetime UTC to local time in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have two pieces of data being returned in JSON:

```
"startTimeUTC":"2018-07-03T21:00:00.000Z"

"siteTimeZone":-4.0"
```

I am then doing this in PHP:

```
$start = date_format(date_create($event['startTimeUTC']), 'Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

Which returns this:

```
2018-07-03 09:00:00
```

I am not sure how I subtract the timezone offset from the original time.

The expected time should be: 05:00:00 PM

I have tried so many different things to get this to work, but have had no luck.

How do I get the correct time to convert to the local time based on the timezone offset?

Comment: You could convert it with `strtotime` then subtract 3600 * 4. https://3v4l.org/oqtlu (not the best approach though)

Comment: It's not a `'Y-m-d h:i:s'` string you got. There is  "T",
 microseconds and a "Z" in there

Comment: @Andreas a standard ISO-8601 date string, `T` is used to separate the date from time.

Comment: @Jonathan Nope! A 8601 has time difference at the end, not a Z. If it was it should have ended with `+00:00`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: @Andreas `Z` is allowed in an 8601 in place of an offset of `00:00` for "zulu" time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The date string already contains the `Zulu` timezone. So you need to create a new `DateTime` object, and then set the new timezone afterwards.

```
$date = new Datetime('2018-07-03T21:00:00.000Z');
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('-4.0'));

var_dump($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')); // 2018-07-03 17:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure how to output the datetime format as you displayed in your comment after the var_dump.

Comment: @iamthestreets - I've updated my answer to use the `format()` method. This is what `date_format` calls internally, so you should be familiar with it.

Comment: Missing a parenthesis for the var_dump. I would update, but "updates need to be at least 6 characters".

Comment: @Jonathan I noticed the missing parameter and this worked great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the timezone as a multiplier to add/subtract from the UTC time.

```
// convert your time via `strtotime` and then add your offset * 3600 (seconds in an hour)
$start = date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($event['startTimeUTC']) + ($event['siteTimeZone'] * 3600)) ;
```

Comment: Any reason why this would output in am? I am using fullcalendar.io and it reads it as 5am instead of 5pm.

Comment: It's because `h` is the 12 hour time format. `H` is the 24 hour time format (with leading zero).

Comment: You want a capital 'H' in `'Y-m-d H:i:s'`